# ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value: '1545042106' for column 'test123' at row 1

Tags: mysql

```
web3.eth.getBlock(12345).then(res => {
connection.query(`INSERT INTO blockdata(bnumber,btimestamp) VALUES ("${res.number}","${res.timestamp}");`)
});
```

I got timestamp already.

I wanna insert data to mysql but got an

> Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE: Incorrect datetime value:
>   '1545042106' for column 'btimestamp' at row 1

Comment: This doesn't seem to be Ethereum related. Probably a better fit for stackoverflow. In any case at first glance, it looks like the column expects the data in a different format, possibly in bytes judging by `b` in `btimestamp`. Check your database column data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shiri's comment, that's a `MySQL` format error, not related to ethereum.

You can try using MySQL's [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) function to convert the timestamp to a DATETIME:

```
web3.eth.getBlock(12345).then(res => {
    connection.query(`INSERT INTO blockdata(bnumber,btimestamp) VALUES ("${res.number}",FROM_UNIXTIME(${res.timestamp}));`)
});
```